# Spring Boot / Spring Data integration tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, integration-testing

Didn't manage to configure Spring Boot for integration testing. Cold you please take a look at the code below:

**Entities**

```
@Entity(name = "Item")
@Table(name = "item")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Item extends CoreEntity {

    @Embedded
    protected CurrencyAmount amount;

    @Column(name = "operation_time")
    protected ZonedDateTime operationTime;

    @Column(name = "description")
    protected String description;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    protected ItemCategory category;

}



@Entity(name = "Income")
@Table(name = "income")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
public class Income extends Item {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "budget_id")
    private Budget budget;

    ...

}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository("incomeDao")
public interface IncomeDao extends JpaRepository<Income, Long> {
}
```

**Test configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "dao.item")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"model"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DaoTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

**Application properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

**Test case**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DaoTestConfiguration.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class IncomeDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private IncomeDao incomeDao;

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        Budget budget = Budget.getBulider().setMonth(Month.NOVEMBER).build();
        ItemCategory category = ItemCategory.getBuilder()
                .setItemGroup(ItemGroup.INCOME)
                .setCathegoryName("Salary")
                .build();
        Income income = Income.getBuilder()
                .setBudget(budget)
                .setCurrencyAmount(new CurrencyAmount(Currency.getInstance("USD"), BigDecimal.TEN))
                .setDescription("Monthly salary")
                .setItemCategory(category)
                .setOperationTime(ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 1, 12, 12, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")))
                .build();
        incomeDao.save(income);

        assertThat(incomeDao.findAll()).containsExactly(income);
    }
}
```

I tried a different configuration (its last edition), but all the time I get the same exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Таблица "INCOME" не найдена
Table "INCOME" not found; SQL statement:
insert into income (model/amount, currency, category_id, description, operation_time, budget_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [42102-196]
```

More over the nature of the exception is strange as the main idea to let spring boot to auto-generate schema according to entity annotations. Thus, at the moment of insertion spring had to create table but looks that it didn't. If someone give an idea what I did wrong or if somebody already faced such an issue - please let me knkow. Thanks.

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` are basically mutually exclusive. You either want a full blown test `@SpringBootTest` or a slice, but not both. Also you are trying very hard to work around Spring Boot with your `@Configuration` class there is nothing in there that Spring Boot doesn't already configure for you. Work with the framework not around it.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work out. I agree that configuration with spring boot should be small as Boot itself stands for auto-configuration but all the auto-configs I found in official documentation or googling din't suit.

Comment: Everything you have in that configuration is already done for you by Spring Boot... It doesn't add anything..

Comment: Agree. According to examples @DataJpaTest should be enough (tacking in account that spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-boot-starter-test and h2 are in pom without versions), but I get: `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) `. Can the issue be in boot dependencies?

Comment: If there is no `@SpringBootConfiguration` annotated class found it means it cannot find your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. Which generally comes due to weird packaging (i.e. no shared root package like you have judging from the `@Configuration` you posted).

Answer (score 1):

Either use `@SpringBootTest` (full loaded context) or use `@DataJpaTest` (JPA context).

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) :

> Annotation that can be used in combination with
>   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) for a typical JPA test. Can be used when
>   a test focuses only on JPA components.
>
> ...
>
> If you are looking to load your full application configuration, but
>   use an embedded database, you should consider @SpringBootTest combined
>   with @AutoConfigureTestDatabase rather than this annotation.

Besides, by specifying `DaoTestConfiguration` as configuration class in  your test class :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = DaoTestConfiguration.class)
```

you don't rely on default values for embedded database provided Spring boot as 
in `DaoTestConfiguration` , you declared the bean :

```
public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
}
```

Either don't create this datasource and let Spring Boot do the job to create it or else specify also the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` in the datasource bean declaration.

Comment: Thank you, but If I remove @DataJpaTest then will get:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!`. If remove @SpringBootTest(classes = DaoTestConfiguration.class) then: `Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test`

Comment: It is probably because `DaoTestConfiguration` doesn't specify `@EnableAutoConfiguration`. So entities are not found.  Besides, according to the package where `DaoTestConfiguration` is located, default package to search bean candidates changes. Do you really need to use `DaoTestConfiguration` ? Just remove it or else ensure you specify correct and minimum Spring Boot configuration.

Answer (score 1):

add this property  in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Added, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a @DataJpaTest, my answer is similar to Bhusan Umiyal, but use `create` instead of `update`.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And like everyone else in here has said, don't use it along with `@SpringBootTest`.

Also make sure that your test classes are in the same or sub package with the main Spring Boot application class.